# Mocha testing path argument in package.json

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, chai-http

Note: I'm a complete noob to nodejs. Please explain your answer in such a way somebody who has experience in other programming languages, but creates his very first nodejs application can understand =).

I'm trying to write a simple test application which should automate testing an external service against an OpenApi 3.0 specification.

I've pulled together some example code in order to attempt to automate testing the OpenApi spec against an external service which implements the API using mocha and chai.

My problem seems now that my mocha test modules cannot be found.

I get the following error message:

```
> client_test@1.0.0 test /Users/user1/dev/app/app-rt/client_test
> mocha ./test/**/*.test.js

/Users/user1/dev/app/app-rt/client_test/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1163
else throw err
^

Error: The "path" argument must be an absolute filepath
```

My package.json:

```
{
    "name": "client_test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Client Tester",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha ./test/**/*.test.js"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "dependencies": {
        "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
        "chai-openapi-response-validator": "^0.2.4",
        "mocha": "^6.2.0",
        "nock": "^11.3.2"
    }
}
```

The little test application in test/client_all.test.js:

```
// Set up Chai
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

// Import this plugin
const chaiResponseValidator = require('chai-openapi-response-validator');

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081';

// Load an OpenAPI file (YAML or JSON) into this plugin
chai.use(chaiResponseValidator('./spec/app.json'));

// Get an HTTP response using chai-http
chai.use(require('chai-http'));

// Write your test (e.g. using Mocha)
describe('GET /zones', function() {
         it('should satisfy OpenAPI spec', async function() {

            const res = chai.request(baseUrl).get('/zones');

            expect(res.status).to.equal(200);

            // Assert that the HTTP response satisfies the OpenAPI spec
            expect(res).to.satisfyApiSpec;
           });
});
```

Can you help me figure out why the paths cannot resolved, and how to fix it? Feel free to comment on the test code as well, if you think I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the package `chai-openapi-response-validator`. Try something like this:

```
// Import this plugin
const chaiResponseValidator = require('chai-openapi-response-validator');

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8081';

// New code
const path = require('path')
const specPath = path.resolve('./spec/app.json')

// Load an OpenAPI file (YAML or JSON) into this plugin
chai.use(chaiResponseValidator(specPath));
```

Make sure the path to the `app.json` file is relative to the `package.json` file, or use another method to convert it to an absolute path.